# Still confused by the Abramsverse

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009, star-trek-into-darkness, star-trek-reboot

Being a lifelong Trek fan, I am still bewildered by the Abramsverse Trek films.

The use of the black hole created by the red matter apparently affects space-time much like the quantum rift from the TNG episode "Parallels" (7th season).  Spock is not just thrown back in time, but also into another quantum reality.  Unlike a parallel universe, as stated by Uhura in the film, the quantum reality would have the changes to objects like starship and uniform designs, character ages and origins, and even looks. This would also explain why Khan, who was born a Sihk warrior at least 150 years before any 'time change' that created the events in the film happened, suddenly became a scrawny white guy.  It also explains why the design of Federation ships is so radically different.  Is there anything out there that can give a good in-universe answer as to why so much has changed BEFORE the actual intervention of "old Spock" and Nero?

How this is supposed to play out canonically?

EDIT: Apparently, my question leads readers astray.
What I want to know is this: Is there a canon-based reason for the dramatic changes seen in the Abramsverse?

Comment: I can't help thinking this is more of a rant than a question... They cast an actor who they felt would do the best job of the role. How's it different to having an Austrailian playing James Bond?

Comment: There isn't a canonical explanation for changes earlier in the timeline, you're right, but if you'd like some headcanon, I like the explanation used in the Flashpoint comics: when Spock and Nero travelled back in time, it created ripples that travelled throughout the timestream, changing other things as well.  Totally unofficial, but if you need an in-universe explanation for something that was basically just a casting decision, it works.

Comment: "how this is supposed to play out canonically?"  What is the "This" referring to in this sentence? I am unable to find what your question actually is.

Comment: @Liath - I am asking how it has been or if it has been addressed in-universe?  I am suggesting what I think to be the best case explanation, but I want to know if there is any actual in-universe explanation.

Comment: VTC - This is a rant; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @ Christopher Lee - I explained "this" in the paragraph following the first.

Comment: The only actual question I see in here is "Is there an in-universe explanation for Khan's cross-timeline change in appearance?"  If that is your question, pretty much everything else should be edited out.  If it's not... pretty much everything should still be edited.

Comment: Okay, let me edit this question then since only one person seems to have gotten what I was asking...

Comment: How do you explain the "This" after you say "this". Shouldn't the "this" be referencing something prior to saying "this"? There is no real question here.  In the same way I can not ask "Who is he?" before I referenced who the subject of "he" is.

Comment: @ Christopher Lee - Better?

Comment: What is the conundrum? You do not explain what the conundrum actually is.

Comment: A better question would be "How could a single event (Nero coming through the wormhole and destroying the Kelvin) cause changes to occur as far as 150 years BACK through the new timeline?" or something similar. That said, don't feel bad - we're ALL still confused by the reboot.

Comment: @ Christopher Lee - Edited for your pleasure.  :P

Comment: It's interesting that you focus on Khan's race. Why is his race important? What does it mean to you?

Comment: It means Kurtzman and Orci don't know squat about Trek.  There were several "super" humans during the Eugenics Wars.  Khan Noonien Singh was one of the most powerful and most brutal.  Even with the retcon done on the Eugenics Wars in Enterprise, they still did not change his background.  So why not leave Khan's origins the same if all that had changed was the timeline before Khan's creation?

Comment: Ricardo Montelban was also a "white guy", the child of two Europeans (his parents were Spanish immigrants to Mexico), with no South Asian ancestry that I know of. Sikhism is a religion rather than an ethnic group after all (even if most followers are South Asian for historical reasons), so there's no in-universe reason Khan couldn't have been of primarily European ancestry in both timelines, perhaps raised by an adoptive family to explain his non-European name.

Answer (score 2):

There is no in-universe explanation, but there doesn't need to be one. That is not because we should merely suspend disbelief, but because you're looking at the changes in the wrong way. In short, **the changes did not even occur, in-universe**.

Consider for a moment that Captain Picard in the future doesn't *actually* look like Patrick Stewart. We're seeing an *interpretation* of events, like when the Voyager crew went into the Q Continuum. What we see on TV isn't actually how the events would look, were they real: it's just been made that way so that we can understand it in the context of our own lives. Also, because you have to cast actors to play roles.

So when you look at the design aesthetics of the original reality's world, and compare it with the design aesthetics of the new reality's world, you're insinuating that the changes you detect have something to do with that fictional reality. They don't. They're just an updated/altered interpretation for the screen, purely a result of the interpretation having been produced at a different era in our own lives.

*Neither* aesthetic is the "correct" one.

It's the same as many casting changes (although some are woven into the fabric of a narrative; e.g. Dr Weir in *Stargate: Atlantis*): nobody asked for an in-universe explanation for Saavik radically changing her facial structure between ST2 and ST3. It's because **the change *did not occur* in-universe**.

Comment: I can understand an aesthetic change.  We see a lot of that from TNG on as each series got more money and progressed in special effects technology. I also understand casting issues. You can't recast 70 and 80 year olds and dead people to play younger versions of themselves.

What I don't understand is why they couldn't simply use improved effects and a bigger budget to give us the same feel as TOS?  I don't mind better looking computers compared to the old "lit jewels" models of TOS, but such drastic changes on such an established franchise seem to be very out-of-touch.

Comment: @MightyFerengi: “such drastic changes” – which ones, exactly?

Comment: I listed two in my question, but there is also the question of Delta Vega (Vulcan has no moon), an Enterprise that can now travel through atmosphere and submerge itself as well, Klingon head piercings...

Comment: I would not call a Klingon head piercing a "drastic change".

Comment: It does if it does not fit in the Klingon culture.  Why would the destruction of 40 Klingon warships cause Klingons to suddenly take to wearing jewelry?

Comment: drastic -"likely to have a strong or far-reaching effect; radical and extreme." I do not see piecing to have a far-reaching radical and/or extreme effect. Or to phrase it into a question, "How has the addition of a piercing radically and extremely affected the Star Trek universe?"

Comment: Going from a strictly utilitarian culture focused on honor through combat to one more concerned with physical appearances.  It'd make more sense if it were a tattoo, but facial jewelry, particularly when a head-butt is how Klingons like to have fun, does not seem to be the smartest way to go.

Comment: Ok but "How has the addition of a piercing radically and extremely affected the Star Trek universe?"   I could say that having long hair in combat does not seem the smartest way to go, but that would just be a subjective judgement.

Comment: Yes, but Klingons don't go around pulling each other's hair as a means of entertainment.

Comment: @MightyFerengi: It's amusing that you think you have such a good grasp of Klingon culture that you can wave away a head piercing as not "fitting in the Klingon culture". We saw next to _nothing_ of Klingon culture throughout the franchise. You're aware that the Klingon empire spans not just _an entire planet_ but multiple, right? You know how much cultures and appearances vary just on our own planet so why is a head piercing so hard to accept? Apparently you've made the traditional mistake of taking the appearance of ~1000 warriors as representative of an entire species. That's _racist_! ;)

Comment: @ Lightness - I think we saw quite a bit of the Klingon culture thorughout TNG and even more in DS9.  Sure, we get a baseline in TNG, but DS9 gave us more depth of the people who live in the Empire.  We even get the fat Klingon restauranteur, definitely not a warrior!  The same theme is still present: Klingons are minimalists.  They don't believe in trappings and pleasure as we see it. They don't even have words or phrases like "Please" and "Thank you" in their language. To a Klingon, the highest achievement is that of a renown warrior.  Even those who are not warriors emulate those who are.

Comment: @MightyFerengi: Missed my point entirely.

Comment: @ Lightness: No, I understand what you are trying to say, but the fact remains that Klingons are Klingons.  What you are saying is that non-Warriors and Warriors would be the same, yet we have seen repeatedly that Klingon warriors have a code, a manner of conduct, and an air of nobility about them.  If what you postulate is true, than Klingon warriors are nothing more than a minority of rabble-rousers.

Comment: @MightyFerengi: ["Klingon daughters traditionally were given a piece of jewelry called a jinaq when they became old enough to select a mate. (TNG: 'Birthright, Part II')"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Klingon) Just one example of your racial generalisation failing at the gate.

Comment: BTW the Enterprise could always travel through atmosphere (TOS: "Tomorrow is Yesterday") and, as far as I'm aware, there was never any indication that it was prohibited from underwater rest in the original timeline. Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: A jinaq was a piece of Klingon jewelry, basically a necklace or pendant, not a facial piercing. Also of note is that it is tradition, not for beauty, that women get the jinaq. The point is that a FACIAL PIERCING is not in line with what Klingons wear because it would interfere with their head-butt ritual and the use of a head-butt in combat.  Of course, since this is a completely different Trek, I guess the point could be made that these Klingons don't head-butt each other.  They probably don't drink bloodwine, eat gagh, or sing opera either...

Comment: @Mighty: Now you're invoking a pretty ridiculous slippery slope argument.

Answer (score 0):

"...why so much has changed BEFORE the actual intervention of "old Spock" and Nero?"

Don't you answer your own question here?

"The use of the black hole ... affects space-time much like the quantum rift ... Spock is not just thrown back in time, but also into another quantum reality. ... the quantum reality would have the changes to objects like starship and uniform designs, character ages and origins, and even looks. ... . This would also explain why Khan, who was born a Sihk warrior at least 150 years before any 'time change' that created the events in the film happened, suddenly became a scrawny white guy."

Comment: That's my suggestion, but I am looking for something more in-universe.

Comment: So what is the conundrum?

Comment: "The new Star Trek reboot universe is very aesthetically different from the original series aesthetics. Is there an in-universe explanation that ties these aesthetic differences together or explains the changes aesthetically?"   Is this your question?

Comment: I removed "conundrum" from my question in favor of a more direct question.

Comment: "I realize all too clearly that it was nothing more than a chance for Rod Roddenberry and Paramount to make some money,"  I am not sure how this sentence adds to your question? Why is this sentence needed? Also, what is the "it" mentioned in that sentence? I am unable to find the subject of the "it".

Comment: Again revised for your scrutiny.  :D

Comment: I see the change, but how does the following add to you question? "I realize all too clearly that the films were nothing more than a chance for Rod Roddenberry and Paramount to make some money... "   I feel it is a rant that has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Edited for clarity.  :P

Comment: Why do you suggest that there is "nothing more" to Star Trek then "mak[ing] some money"?   that just seems like an off topic rant thrown on top of the question. You could have just said "Please respond with an in-universe answer" and not make subjective claims about Star Trek being nothing More than money.

Comment: Not Star Trek as a whole, just the Abramsverse.

Comment: yes I realize not Star Trek as a whole, but my point still remains. It is a subjective rant or "dig" at the Star Trek film that should be removed from this question.

Comment: Edited yet again just because I like you so much.  :P